# Display website in webview without zoom

Tags: android, webview

I have a spinner and when an item is selected an html attached to the item is displayed on a webview.

And it looks like this after an item is selected:

[image: With zoom]

Then the user can zoom-out but I want to display the web like this from default, it's there any option for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) 
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
```

Comment: Worked just fine and fixed the display of some tables thank you